# What is the maximum prefix size routed in the IPv6 Internet?

Tags: ipv6, bgp

In v4, most of the operators filter BGP updates for prefixes longer than a /24, to preserve the size of the full view.

What about IPv6 ? Is there such "convention" that stands out ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These days it's usually at /48, and it's very unlikely to ever be longer.

There are still AS' filtering longer than /32 though, but they should all have a default at this point (Verizon were a hold-out, but I believe they've given up).

There are also AS' filtering on allocation lengths, so if you got a /32 they might require you advertise it as such (based on the various RIR's documented allocation policies).

Comment: Wow, filtering on allocation length ? That makes impossible for a content provider to serve geo-based prefixes, right ?

Comment: Not really, if they're disparate networks the RIR's allow multiple allocations in the correct space (at least ARIN, RIPE & APNIC do). There was a recent NANOG thread about this.

Comment: I should really subscribe to NANOG then, even if I'm french !

Comment: It's as close to a global NOG as it gets, although posting non-North American content usually gets complaints.

Comment: @BenjaminA.: This has been discussed on FRnOG too. See http://www.mail-archive.com/frnog@frnog.org/msg22235.html